# Future.cancel(true) does not reliably cancel/interrupt thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I try to execute several tasks in parallel with a CompletionService. The problems arise, when i try to implement cancelation.

Here is a sketch of the code I use:

```
void startTasks(int numberOfTasks) throws Exception {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    CompletionService<TaskResultType> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<TaskResultType>(executor);
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<TaskResultType> results = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<BenchmarkResult>();
    ArrayList<Future> futures = new ArrayList<Future>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks ; i++) {
        TypeOfTask task = ... ; 
        Future future = completionService.submit(task);
        futures.add(future);
    }

    boolean failed = false;
    Throwable cause = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
        try {
            Future<TaskResultType> resultFuture = completionService.take();
            TaskResultType result = resultFuture.get();
            results.add(result);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            failed = true;
            cause = e.getCause();
            /* cancel all other running tasks in case of failure in one task */
            for (Future future : futures) {
                future.cancel(true);
            }
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            // consume (planned cancellation from calling future.cancel())
        }

    }
    executor.shutdown();
    // code to throw an exception using cause
}
```

The tasks implement `Callable`.

When I now throw an exception in one of the tasks in most of the cases it works out fine, i.e. I immediately get the CancellationExceptions from the other tasks and the tasks finish immediately (lets call this case A). But sometimes (lets call this case B), some of the tasks finish first and then throw the CancellationException. Future.cancel(true) returned true in both cases for all tasks (except the one with the initial ExecutionException, because this one was already canceled).

I check for the interrupted flag with Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted(), in the tasks that do complete (i.e. the tasks where the cancelation is unsuccessful), the interrupted flag is set to false.

All that seems to be very strange behavior in my eyes. Anybody any idea what the problem could be?

**Update**

The best idea so far I have is, that somewhere deep within the code comprising the task (only some high level code is from myself) the interrupted status is consumed, e.g. by a catched InterruptedException which doesn't call Thread.interrupt() to reestablish the status. The exact time  the interrupted flag is set by Future.cancel() might vary slightly due to scheduling of the threads, that would explain the inconsistent behavior. Would a consumed interrupted status explain the behavior of case B?

Comment: How do you test the interrupted flag in a job that has already completed?  If it already completed then no code is running, right?

Comment: Without seeing the code in your Task, we can't help you

Comment: I suspect your problem is that one of the tasks is doing IO or otherwise blocked and is not checking for `Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()`.  So even though you have canceled the `Future` and the thread is interrupted, this doesn't get detected.  Does your program hang or does it finish?  If it hangs can you do a thread dump to see which of the threads is hung up?

Comment: @Gray No, i'm checking while the task is still running.

Comment: @Gray The program finishes in both cases

Comment: @dkatzel That would be a lot of code...

Comment: I've moved my comments to an answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer per your update.  So what happens when it fails is that some of the threads may seem to ignore the interrupt and continue to run?

Comment: Can you please post your Task class? I think that's where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

> But sometimes, some of the tasks finish first and then throw the CancellationException. Future.cancel(true) returned true in both cases for all tasks (except the one with the initial ExecutionException, because this one was already canceled).

If your program was not finishing (or taking a long time to finish after an exception is thrown) then I suspect your problem is that one of the tasks is doing IO or otherwise blocked and is not checking for `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`. So even though you have canceled the Future and the thread is interrupted, this doesn't get detected.

However, it seems like the program is finishing.  So I'm not sure what the error case is here.  If you catch an exception you call `future.cancel(true)` on all of the futures in the list.  The one that threw and the ones that have already finished should all return `false` since they can't be canceled.  The ones that returned `true` from cancel should have been interrupted.

For example. if the 2nd to last thread throws an exception then `future.cancel(true)` should only return `true` for the last thread running.

One thing to do is to remove the futures as they finish so you don't re-cancel already completed jobs.  But all that might do is mask the issue you are seeing now:

```
Future<TaskResultType> resultFuture = completionService.take();
futures.remove(resultFuture);
```

**Update:**

It is highly possible that some code is swallowing the interrupt.  It happens all of the time unfortunately.  If some of the threads are not finishing immediately when they are canceled and are running to completion then this is probably what is happening.

Comment: So I still don't understand what the problem is @jvf.

Comment: All the tasks are long running. In one of the tasks I throw an exception right after starting it. This results in an ExecutionException, which then results in calling Future.cancel(). In the cases where all works fine, this immediately results in canceling the other tasks, so more futures become available from the completion service, all these futures trow an CancellationException on Future.get(). I would expect, that calling cancel() on a running tasks should always immediately cancel it...

Answer (score 0):

> But sometimes, some of the tasks finish first and then throw the
>   CancellationException.

Could it be the case that you cancel a task, it's normally interrupted (in this state you may think that it returns a result, but for the CompletionService it's cancelled), the future is being returned by `take()`, you call `future.get()` and there is the `CancellationException`.

You could also have a look at Guava's [`Futures.allAsList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList%28java.lang.Iterable%29), which seems to be doing a very similar thing:

> Creates a new ListenableFuture whose value is a list containing the values of all its input futures, if all succeed. If any input fails, the returned future fails.